# How to open a document present in EC2 server in local machine?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deployed my Django Project in AWS EC2 server.
My website got hosted successfully.
Iam running a python code on click of a HTML button to open am Excel Sheet.
Python code to open the excel sheet is given below:

import webbrowser

a_website = "C:\python\Python38\result.xlsx"

webbrowser.open_new(a_website)

The excel sheet is opening in the EC2 server. But I need Excel sheet to be displayed in my local machine on which Iam clicking the HTML button on the hosted Website.

How will I open the Excel sheet present on EC2 server in my local machine?

Comment: What webserver are you using the serve Django?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some more research into handling serving files with a webserver. Depending on the webserver there's different ways to send files from the server to client. For example: Apache allow you to use the xsendfile module. Be sure to set the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header when you serve the file.